# Why CLOB slower than VARCHAR2 in Oracle?

Tags: python, oracle

Currently, we have a table containing a varchar2 column with 4000 characters, however, it became a limitation as the size of the 'text' being inserted can grow bigger than 4000 characters, therefore we decided to use CLOB as the data type for this specific column, what happens now is that both the insertions and selections are way too slow compared to the previous varchar2(4000) data type.
We are using Python combined with SqlAlchemy to do both the insertions and the retrieval of the data. In simple words, the implementation itself did not change at all, only the column data type in the database.

Does anyone have any idea on how to tweak the performance?

Comment: Don't be so sure of nothing changing in the middle. Changing from VC to CLOB affects every bit of the pipeline between the client and the database--all of the layers must now adjust themselves to being prepared to receive a gigabyte of text data in one call, and all of the layers will have to deal with things like CLOB locators and such, even if this is hidden beneath a library call. CLOBs are trouble most of the time, use them sparingly. With that said, they are often the best tool for a job.

Comment: @TadHarrison yes, I meant I didn't change my own codebase, indeed the library itself handles varchar2(n) and CLOB data types differently I've checked the code myself. Thank you for the tip anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> There are two kinds of storage for CLOB's
>
> 1. in row
>
> The clob is stored like any other column in the row. This can only be
> done for clob up to a certain size (approx 4k). Clobs larger than this
> will stored in a separate segment (the "lobsegment")
>
> 2. out of row
>
> The clob is always stored out of the row in the lobsegment
>
> You can which is being used for your table by checking USER_LOBS.
>
> It is possible, particularly in the first 'in row' instance that your
> table consume more blocks for the "normal" rows because of the
> interspersed lob data, and hence takes longer to scan.

See here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9536389800346757758

If your LOB is stored separately, you have to navigate a separate indexing architecture and additional data files to get to the data. This will slow things down because of the additional background operations and disk I/O involved. There isn't much you can do about that except minimize the number of operations that access the LOB data, or get faster storage media.

Comment: While this info is correct, it is unlikely the source of the questioner's performance problem. The LOB calls between client driver and database are where the real cost is. That  isn't impacted by inline vs. out of line.

Answer (score 0):

LOBs have to be read and/or written behind the scenes by your client driver using a loop that reads or writes into a small buffer and keeps doing so until it reaches the end of the LOB. That buffer is smaller than you'd want it to be, and so it becomes quite chatty (lots of back and forth packets across the network between client and database). Not to mention creating the LOB locator and closing it. Too much back-and-forth.

Given that you recently made this change because some data exceeded 4KB, that suggests that most of your data is < 4KB. Take advantage of that situation and work with those < 4KB values using varchar2(4000), and only use CLOB where you have to (with values > 4KB).

Actual implementation of course depends on what you're doing. But this concept should be applied in some way. If you are selecting data, then select like this:

```
SELECT CAST(clobcolumn AS varchar2(4000)) clobcolumn_as_varchar
  FROM mytable
 WHERE NVL(dbms_lob.getlength(clobcolumn),0) <= 4000
   AND [other predicates you need]
```

Then do a separate select for the larger rows:

```
SELECT clobcolumn
  FROM mytable
 WHERE NVL(dbms_lob.getlength(bigcolumn),0) > 4000
   AND [other predicates you need]
```

For inserts, define a client variable that will be mapped to a varchar, and one that will be mapped to a CLOB, use the first for the < 4KB values, the larger for the >4KB values, separate insert statements. Even if the varchar2 version is inserted into a CLOB column, Oracle will do the implicit conversion for you within the database, and it's fast. The key thing is, the network conversation used varchar2.

Note that this approach can make a world of difference if the great majority of your values are small (< 4KB). If most of them are over the 4KB boundary, then there's little benefit.

Comment: Thanks for your input, we'll be doing some PoCs on alternative implementations, I'll put this suggestion on the table and if it works I'll get back here.

Comment: Another version of this is to have two columns, one varchar2, the other CLOB. You use the CLOB col only when you need to, and you can use a view, a derived column or a third consolidated CLOB col populated by trigger to combine them on the database end if you don't want downstream processes to have to juggle 2 cols.

Answer (score -1):

You could also ask your DBA if possible to upgrade the DB to max_string_size=EXTENDED, then the max VARCHAR2 size would be 32K.

Comment: Just be aware that that's a one-way street. Once you switch to EXTENDED, it applies to the entire database, and you can never go back.

Comment: ... that's one of the reason: "ask your DBA" !...

Comment: Also, VARCHAR2 fields over 4000 bytes are silently converted to CLOBs by Oracle anyway, so it doesn't really solve your problem.

Comment: See here for example of extended VARCHAR2 being stored as a LOB: https://connor-mcdonald.com/2021/03/04/extended-varchar2-and-the-hidden-lob/

Comment: Under the covers, it implements those extended varchar2s as CLOBs... no benefit.